# Virtualization disabled on Windows10, enabled in BIOS

Tags: cpu, bios, virtualization, docker, hyper-v

My Windows 10 claims that virtualization is disabled in firmware, even though I have it enabled in BIOS, checked that my CPU supports it and restarted my machine several times to check whether it changes something.

I want to install docker and I follow the tutorial from the [Docker documentation for installation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/) to the letter. If I try to run Docker Desktop, it says Virtualization is disabled in BIOS (it is not).

- **My CPU is**: Intel Core i5 3470, Ivy Bridge
- **My Motherboard**: ASUSTeK Computer INC, P8B75-M LX PLUS Rev X.0x, Chipset Ivy Bridge (rev09), Southbridge P75/B75 (rev04), LPCIO Nuvoton NCT6779
- **BIOS**: American Megatrend Inc., v0501, 10/10/2012
- **My system is**: Windows 10 Professional

From reading many similar questions on this site, I see that people frequently recommend installing Hyper-V Platform. This is what my Windows Features looks like - it says I cannot install Hyper-V, because virtualization support is disabled in the firmware.

But I think I just enabled it (booted to BIOS (it's UEFI with mouse and pretty fancy UI though), found CPU Features, Intel Virtualization Technology: Enabled). According to [this page](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/68316/intel-core-i53470-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html), Virtualization is supported by my CPU.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What steps can I take to pinpoint what exactly is wrong on my machine? Don't know how relevant this is, but I installed the system on this machine about 14 days ago, so it is still relatively fresh.

**Edit** - added details about my motherboard & bios. Following are the screens taken with my phone of what my BIOS looks like.

[image: Main screen of BIOS]

[image: virtualization option in bios]

Comment: What is your computer model? Your motherboard? Your BIOS settings (take a screenshot using your phone)?

Comment: hey @harrymc thanks for getting back to me, I have attached the requested information & screens

Comment: What software could you have installed that could e interfering with Docker and Hyper-V? Do you have Android Studio installed by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound - I do not have Android Studio. I have installed Visual Studio + Visual Studio Code (no HW-acceleration/virtualization options as far as I remember), IntelliJ, Steam, Unity (Hub) + dev pack. Also, no Antivirus (within my risk appetite).

Comment: There has to be something that has been installed using the virtualization otherwise you would be able to enable Hyper-V. Have you installed Docker, but are getting the error, when you attempt to launch it by chance? What about VMWare or VirtualBox?

Comment: Make sure the Android emulator isn’t installed since you do have Visual Studio installed you might have accidentally or intentionally installed it. You should also uninstall Intel HAXM if it’s installed

Comment: Yes, I have installed the docker and do get an error when attempting to launch it. Should I uninstall it? HAXM is not on my machine, and Android Emulator is not there either.

Comment: Strange: The [P8B75-M LX PLUS](https://www.asus.com/SupportOnly/P8B75M_LX_PLUS/HelpDesk_BIOS/) has an ASUS BIOS Version 0906 from 2014/09/12, but you're using Megatrend v0501 from 10/10/2012. If you intend trying the ASUS one, ensure you have an installation disk for the Megatrend one before doing that.

Answer (score -1):

I had to enable SGX option on the same page (Advanced > CPU configuration) (ASRock B460 motherboard).

Comment: SGX has absolutely nothing to do with hardware virtualization.

Comment: @Ramhound, well, probably not, I'm not familiar with it. But you can find this solution on google and it helped me: the virtualization status in task manager changed to "enabled".

Comment: Ask a well researched question and I will be happy to answer it.  I won't be answering a question through the comment section

Comment: While we're glad you solved your problem, given what you've said, you had a different problem than the one presented by OP.